# Machine shmurah whole-wheat matza?

Tags: food, passover, product-recommendation, health-safety-shmira, matzah

Usually in the store I can find machine-made shmurah matzah, and machine-made whole-wheat matza, but never machine-made whole-wheat shmurah matzah. Does anyone know if such a product is available, and/or where to find it?

Comment: [tag:health-safety-shmira]?

Comment: @msh210, whole wheat is a "health food" thing, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haddar makes such a product.

https://www.aviglatt.com/Haddar-Whole-Wheat-Shmura-Matzos-16-oz/9479/

http://www.israelisuper.com/Haddar-Whole-Wheat-Shmura-Matzos-16-oz/9479/

Comment: And no one in America makes it as far as I know; I wonder what the supply and demand are.